# Some of the damaged parts are missing from an image (using image processing with python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

I am trying to display damaged parts of an image in order to restore them. I am quite new to image processing and I'm using cv2. Here are the images I'm working on.

[original damaged image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq6IH.png)

[required mask image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMSeh.png)

And I'm getting the following image:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoebE.png)

```
import cv2
dim = (512,512)
im_color = cv2.imread("couple.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
im_color = cv2.resize(im_color,dim)
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh=200, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im_thresh_gray = cv2.bitwise_and(im_gray, mask[0])
mask3 = cv2.cvtColor(mask[1], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
im_thresh_color = cv2.bitwise_and(im_color, mask3)
cv2.imshow("original image", im_color)
cv2.imshow("binary mask", mask[1])
cv2.imshow("3 channel mask", mask3)
cv2.imshow("im_thresh_gray", im_thresh_gray)
cv2.imshow("im_thresh_color", im_thresh_color)
cv2.imwrite("repaired.png",mask3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Some of the damaged parts are being missed. please can anyone help me out ?!

Comment: Any reason not to use inpainting? https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html

Comment: looks like a quite hard problem to me

Comment: I think it may be possible to solve using U-Net or GAN networks, but you'll need to train them first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what @Mark Setchell suggested is what you are looking for. The example contains a very similar example.